# How do I delete a table row as well as the corresponding array element in the controller for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am displaying table records from an array in a view, but have added delete and edit buttons to each row, in which I want to be able to delete the dynamically instantiated table row when the delete button is pressed, as well as the array item from the array that populated it. I want the page to refresh as well.

**Past attempts:**

I have tried creating forms with submit_tags for deleting, but to no avail, as well as routing and creating destroy and delete functions. I have looked up solutions to this for hours but none worked for me.

I am a beginner at Ruby. The code is a bit untidy due to me having inserted solutions, trying to test them, and then deleting.

**CODE:**

I have created an array in my controller called @db_data, where a search button only displays specific elements with @hospital_data:

```
   class HospitalsController < ApplicationController
  

    def index
    #ONLY CHANGE THIS TO DATABASE DATA IN 3D ARRAY FORMAT!!
    @db_data=[["1","Helen Joseph"],["2","Bara"],["3","Charlotte Maxeke"]]
    #Format is [[hospital ID], [hospital name]]
    #SEARCH BAR CODE 

    
    #DON'T CHANGE BELOW CODE!!==========================
    
    @data = params[:searchHospitals]
    if @data.blank?
        @hospitals_array=@db_data   
    else
        @hospitals_array=@db_data.select{|x,y| y.match(/#{@data}/) }    
    end

    #===================================================

  end



end
```

The html.erb file just for the display table is as follows:

```
<!--TABLE-->

<div class="m-4">

  <table id="cartTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Hospital ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Hospital Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

<tbody>
  <!--loop through each item in hospital array-->



  <% @hospitals_array.each_with_index do |hosp_element, index| %>
     
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="col-5" >  <%= hosp_element.first %> </th>
      <td  class="col-6"><%= hosp_element.last %> </td> 

      <!--edit and delete functionality-->


 <td class="col-1">
    <div   class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark"  >Edit</button>
   
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark"  >Delete</button>
  </div>
  </td>
    </tr>

   
  
    <% end %>


  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

My route for this is currently:

```
get "/hospitals",to: "hospitals#index"
```

Comment: Where are you using your array element in view?

Comment: Can you explain why you think using an array as your data source is a good idea instead of something sane like for example a database? How do you expect to pass the state of this array from request to request?

Comment: @max I was experimenting with front-end since the database we are using has not been sorted out yet. I will still need to create scaffolds for the database tables

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari I am using it in the table row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am not sure if I understand your problem in 100% but I guess you want to add edit and delete buttons to your view.

To delete your rows we have to add few things, at first let's update `routes.rb` file:

```rb
  # For explanation I recommend: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :hospitals, only: [:index, :destroy]
```

then we need to define controller actions for our new routes, I've also refactored your Index action to use ActiveRecord:

```rb
class HospitalsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @hospitals = Hospital.select(:id, :name)
  
    if params[:searchHospitals]
      # It's better to use DB engine for optimization instead of Ruby `.select`
      @hospitals = @hospitals.where("NAME like '%#{params[:searchHospitals]%'")
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @hospital = Hospital.find(params[:id])
    @hospital.destroy

    redirect_to(hospitals_path)
  end
end
```

and finally in the view

```
<% @hospitals.eachx do |hospital| %>
     
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="col-5" >  <%= hospital.id %> </th>
      <td  class="col-6"><%= hospital.name %> </td> 
      <td class="col-1"><%= link_to 'Destroy', micropost, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, class: 'btn btn-outline-dark' %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

For `edit` button you'll have to create another methods in controller and add additional views.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out and let you know if it works